# what does >{} mean inside a table

Tags: tables

Can anyone tell me what does this do? I think I have understood most of the

```
\newenvironment{keywords}{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

  \begin{tabular}{>{}l>{}p{13cm}} 
}{%
  \end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! In this case, it does not have an effect, but in general `>{\command}` lets you execute the macro `\command` at the beginning of the cell. Popular choices for `\command` include `\centering`.

Answer (score 1):

`>{<stuff>}<col spec>` within a `tabular` or `array` column specification will insert `<stuff>` at the start of `<col spec>`. It is introduced by the [`array` package](//ctan.org/pkg/array). As an example,

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\textbullet\space}l}
  First \\ Second \\ Third
\end{tabular}
```

will create a list-like `tabular` with three items.

In your situation, `<stuff>` is empty, and therefore doesn't do anything (and can be removed).

Answer (score 1):

`>{<content>}` command inside the tabular's parameters means that the `<content>` will be executed (if a command) or displayed (if a text) for each cell of the following column (that its type is defined from the upcoming letter -here the `l` and the `p`-). if you add for example `\Large` command inside the first `>{}` (and make it `>{\Large}`), then the first column of your keywords (their name)  will appear as Large in your tabular.

Try it:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newenvironment{keywords}{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

  \begin{tabular}{>{\Large}l>{}p{13cm}} 
}{%
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{keywords}
 test & Here is a long keyword that will exceed one line and break to the second one\\
Another test & Here is a long keyword that will exceed one line and break to the second one\\
\end{keywords}
\end{document}
```

Being emty, they add nothing at all there and so, nothing is displayed or executed.

Instead if they where `@{}` they would remove the extra space between the columns it appears:

Try:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newenvironment{keywords}{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

  \begin{tabular}{>{}l@{}p{13cm}} 
}{%
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{keywords}
 test & Here is a long keyword that will exceed one line and break to the second one\\
Another test & Here is a long keyword that will exceed one line and break to the second one\\
\end{keywords}
\end{document}
```